# How to Download an image from FTP using FTPClient?

Tags: java

I m using this code and try to download an png pic from server .this is code

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
public class NetTest {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    FTPClient client = new FTPClient( );
    OutputStream outStream;
    try {

      client.connect( "server" );
      client.login("noman@mindzone.co.in", "pass");

      String remoteFile = "Pages/page0001.png";
      outStream = new FileOutputStream( "C:\\asd.png" );
      client.retrieveFile(remoteFile, outStream);

    } catch(IOException ioe) {
      ioe.printStackTrace();
      System.out.println( "Error communicating with FTP server." );
    } finally {
      try {
        client.disconnect( );
      } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println( "Problem disconnecting from FTP server" );
      }
    }

  }
}
```

this code gives me no error but when i open the image it shows me invalid image .

Comment: what about downloaded image's size? is it valid?

Comment: downloaded size is almost equal .

Comment: if filesize is small open and see retrieved file as text

Comment: what to look i open it in text and there is lot of text there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this topic is your solution:

http://www.ajaxapp.com/2009/02/21/a-simple-java-ftp-connection-file-download-and-upload/

Comment: i just try to flush but it shows the invalid image as before.

Comment: Added not to the answer dont forget to add permissions to internet and write to sdcard.....

Answer (score 4):

You got corrupted image because the FTPClient uses TEXT_FILE_TYPE by default. So you have to set file type to binary as follows:

```
client.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have neither flushed the output stream nor closed in finally block. Try that.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {

        Log.e("downloadFTP login : ", "Success");
        OutputStream desFileStream = new BufferedOutputStream( new FileOutputStream(desFilePath));
        Log.d(TAG,"FileOutputStream");
        status = mFTPClient.retrieveFile(srcFilePath, desFileStream);
        Log.d(TAG, "4");
        desFileStream.close();

        Log.e("downloadFTP status : ", "" + status);
        Log.d(TAG, "5");
        return status;
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.d(TAG, "download failed");
}
return status;
```

}

Comment: i try it but it is not activity..can you help to me?

Comment: i want download video on FTP server...but it display download failed, not activity